# How to get the Sum from independent two subdocument Arrays in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have this schema

```
    var salesExpenseSchema = new Schema({

        date : {
            month: Number
        },  

        sales: [{amount : Schema.Types.Decimal128}],

        expenses: [{amount : Schema.Types.Decimal128}]

});
```

Example of a database record is like this

```
{
    _id:'5dbac5dfa1488240cbc4f838',
    date:{month:11},
    sales:[{amount:3000},{amount:5000}],
    expenses: [{amount:5000},{amount:500}]
},
{
    _id:'5dbac5dfa1488240cbc4f838',
    date:{month:10},
    sales:[{amount:2000},{amount:5000}],
    expenses: [{amount:500},{amount:800}]
},
{
    _id:'5dbac5dfa1488240cbc4f838',
    date:{month:09},
    sales:[{amount:2000},{amount:4000}],
    expenses: [{amount:200},{amount:300}]
}
```

Now I want to get the Summation of sales and expenses.

I have used Aggregate with $unwind for both sales and expenses like this below:

```
SalesExpense.aggregate([
              {$unwind: "$sales"},
              {$unwind: "$expenses"},
              {$group:{
                    _id:'$_id',
                    sales:{$sum: "$sales.sellPrices"},
                    expenses:{$sum: "$expenses.amount"},
                  }
              },
```

But the problem is... **If one array document has data and the other has no data, then it gives 0 ie, the real summation isn't obtained.** This is to say, if there are sales but no expenses then their sum becomes 0, and vice-versa.

I want to get the summation for both sales and expenses regardless of one of them not having data. How do I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I have edited the question and added the date object in my schema and in the database records: I want to make this summation based on each month, that is to say... each month to have its own sales and expenses... Sort of a timeline with each month having its own sales and expenses.

I have tried using $group before $project

```
{$group:{
_id:'$date.month'}}
```

But it seems not to give the expected results.

I want an output like this one:

```
[
        {
            "month": "11",
            "sales": {
                "$numberDecimal": "8000"
            },
            "expenses": {
                "$numberDecimal": "5500"
            }
        },

        {
            "month": "10",
            "sales": {
                "$numberDecimal": "7000"
            },
            "expenses": {
                "$numberDecimal": "1100"
            }
        },
        {
            "month": "09",
            "sales": {
                "$numberDecimal": "6000"
            },
            "expenses": {
                "$numberDecimal": "500"
            }
        },
    ]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: doesn't this {$sum: "$sales.sellPrices"}  should be {$sum: "$sales.amount"} ?

Comment: @SuleymanSah yes, it should be... I have updated my question

Comment: Ok, does my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes you are right, now I updated the answer, this one is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by month and get the totals like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$date.month",
      "sales": {
        "$sum": {
          "$sum": "$sales.amount"
        }
      },
      "expenses": {
        "$sum": {
          "$sum": "$expenses.amount"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Sample Data:

```
[
  {
    _id: "5dbac5dfa1488240cbc4f838",
    date: {
      month: 11
    },
    sales: [
      {
        amount: 1
      },
      {
        amount: 2
      }
    ],
    expenses: []
  },
  {
    _id: "5dbac5dfa1488240cbc4f839",
    date: {
      month: 11
    },
    sales: [
      {
        amount: 5
      },
      {
        amount: 6
      }
    ],
    expenses: [
      {
        amount: 7
      },
      {
        amount: 8
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "5dbac5dfa1488240cbc4f840",
    date: {
      month: 12
    },
    sales: [],
    expenses: [
      {
        amount: 7
      },
      {
        amount: 8
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 12,
    "expenses": 15,
    "sales": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": 11,
    "expenses": 15,
    "sales": 14
  }
]
```

Playground:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/K9ofoZx5ORI

Comment: Works perfectly... you saved million lives!